# Excluding areas by raster layer in raster calculator

Tags: arcmap

I am conducting a suitability analysis utilizing a road layer that I buffered around. After creating the vector buffer layer, I converted it to a raster. I now want to use the raster calculator in combination with additional raster layers to produce an output raster that excludes those areas within the buffer (the entire 'buffer raster layer'). My issue is that the 'buffer raster layer' only consists of those areas that have been buffered... Any thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated.

Best,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is to make a new copy of the raster with a larger extent. In your geoprocessing environments, set the [Extent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000009000000) to equal the extent of your other raster layers. Then, use the [Copy Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000094000000) tool. The new raster should be the same size as your other data, and you can proceed with raster calculator.